Smooth crosshair
How can I make this crosshair movement smoothly?
Here is my code:
public void renderCrosshair(RenderGameOverlayEvent event) {
    if (mc.gameSettings.guiScale == 2) {
        Minecraft minecraft = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
        if (event.type == ElementType.CROSSHAIRS && isGunInHand(minecraft.thePlayer)) {
            event.setCanceled(true);
            Icon crosshairIcon = ClientProxy.iconRegistry.crosshairIcon;
            double scale = 6.0F + getScaleByMotion(minecraft.thePlayer);
            if (FlansModClient.currentScope == null)
                scale = 45.0F + getScaleByMotion(minecraft.thePlayer);
            GL11.glPushAttrib(16384);
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glEnable(3042);
            OpenGlHelper.glBlendFunc(775, 769, 1, 0);
            GL11.glEnable(3008);
            GL11.glColor3d(1.0D, 1.0D, 1.0D);
            GL11.glTranslated((double)(event.resolution.getScaledWidth() / 2), (double)(event.resolution.getScaledHeight() / 2), 0.0D);
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            ClientProxy.iconRegistry.bindSheet();
            GL11.glRotated(90.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D, 2.0D);
            ClientProxy.iconRegistry.renderIcon(crosshairIcon, -1.9D, (double)(-scale) + 0.1D);
            GL11.glRotated(90.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D, 1.0D);
            ClientProxy.iconRegistry.renderIcon(crosshairIcon, -3.0D, (double)(-scale) - 0.1D);
            GL11.glRotated(90.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D, 1.0D);
            ClientProxy.iconRegistry.renderIcon(crosshairIcon, -3.0D, (double)(-scale) + 0.9D);
        }
    }
}


Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you explain what's not working? What is wrong with this code? What is the result? Please [edit] your post to include a [mre]

Maybe you can [edit] your question and post an image of how the crosshair looks and another image showing how you want it to look?
